# Find equilibrium points of this system?

Tags: control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-in-odes

$\dot x_1 = x_1(1 + x_2)$

$\dot x_2 = -x_2 + x_2^2 + (x_1x_2) - x_1^3$

I have set the left hand side to zero to solve and came out with $x_1 = 0$ everywhere and $x_2=0, +1, -1$.

I was wondering if someone could confirm this for me, or provide me a way to check my answers? Thanks :)

Comment: I tried this code in Mathematica: `Solve[{x1(1+x2)==0,-x2+x2^2+x1 x2-x1^3==0},{x1,x2}]` the equation has three real and two imaginary solutions. So your calculation is _almost_ correct: $x=(0,0),\;(0,1),\;(1,-1)$

Comment: Thanks, I'll give the hand calculations another shot. Since there are 2 imaginary solutions can there be an equilibrium point for these, or just not one we can see in the phase portrait?

Comment: When we are dealing with dynamical systems, our first assumption is the states are _real_ functions of time. So imaginary equilibrium point doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1):

Setting the first equation to zero yields $x_1=0$ or $x_2=-1$:

- In the first case this simplifies the right hand side of equation two to $-x_2+x_2^2$. When equating that to zero yields $x_2=0$ or $x_2=1$. So equilibrium points are $(0,0)$ and $(0,1)$.
- In the second case this simplifies the right hand side of equation two to $2-x_1-x_1^3$. When equating that to zero yields $x_1=1$ and two complex values for $x_1$. So the last equilibrium point is $(1,-1)$.